# Communication Between Raspberry Pi, MQTT or TCP/IP

Tags: tcp, raspberry-pi, ip, mqtt, communication

5 applications between Raspberry Pi in a project I did. 1 "Server will be Client to 4 of them. Will there be more traffic from the tool here, or via TCP/IP or using MQTT? Which is more detailed? Can you help?
Good work...

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are asking here, but under nearly all situations MQTT runs over TCP/IP, so I'll leave you to draw your own conclusions.

Comment: In a project I am doing, 1 of 5 Raspberry Pi will be Server and 4 will be Client. Can I communicate better using MQTT or TCP/IP? Which is better? Can you help me?

Comment: The point I'm trying to make is MQTT **is** TCP/IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The priority and important part for the situation you specify is the delay.

If communication is large data streams instead of multiple, TCP should generally be preferred.
By agreeing with the previous comment, it would be quite appropriate to use MQTT if the code complexity is aimed to be minimized.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on several factors...

- If your needs are for simplicity of code and design, probably MQTT.
- If your communication is large streams of data and point-to-point rather than one-to-many, probably TCP.

Then there's latency to think about... acknowledgement of messages... whether the system should still be able to run with just 3 RasPis... whether it should be expandable to more than 5 RasPis.